# Reading in-memory Avro file from S3: 'AttributeError:'

Tags: python, amazon-s3, avro, bytesio

I'm trying to read Avro files stored in S3 by a vendor and write to a DW. See code below. (Was roughly working from this [S/O thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487588/how-to-read-avro-files-from-s3-in-python).)

```
obj = obj.get()
raw_bytes = obj["Body"].read()
avro_bytes = io.BytesIO(raw_bytes)
reader = DataFileReader(avro_bytes, DatumReader())
```

The code is tripped up at the last line, where I get the error:
`AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'mode'`

That error comes from this spot in the source code, where `DataFileReader` is initialized.

```
def __init__(self, reader: IO[AnyStr], datum_reader: avro.io.DatumReader) -> None:
        if "b" not in reader.mode:
            warnings.warn(avro.errors.AvroWarning(f"Reader binary data from a reader {reader!r} that's opened for text"))
        bytes_reader = getattr(reader, "buffer", reader)
```

I've tried using `avro_bytes` as `StringIO` as well to see if that would help, but it didn't.

Any ideas how to get past that `AttributeError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in version 1.11.0 that has been fixed but a new version hasn't been released: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-3252.

To resolve this, you can do one of the following:

1. Wait until the new version is released
2. Patch the call so that it doesn't do that check
3. Instead of using `BytesIO` you could make your own wrapper object that mimics `BytesIO` but has a `mode` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried searching the active issues but must have missed this one since it’s technically fixed. 

Any idea when the next release is?

Comment: No clue. But I maintain `fastavro` and you could give that a shot to see if it will work for you.